# How to pass Props to the Navigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So, I have such a hierarchy:

`MyList` ---> `MyListNav`

Where `MyList` is a screen containing a list of my stuff;
`MyListNav` is `StackNavigator` wrapped by a `Modal` so as to pop up a small window when `Add New Stuff` button on `MyList` screen is pressed.

As a `StackNavigator`, `MyListNav` has two screens:

```js
export default class Test extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          isVisible: false
          }

        FVN = StackNavigator({
          Find: {screen: Find},
          Add: {screen: Add},
        },{
          mode: 'card',
          headerMode: 'none',
          cardStyle: {
            opacity: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          },
          // ...some transitioning configurations
        })
    }

    render() {
      return(
        <Modal
         isVisible={this.props.isVisible} avoidKeyboard>
         <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
           <View style={styles.modal}>
             <FVN screenProps = {{isVisible: false}}/>
           </View>
         </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </Modal>
      )
    }
```

I know it's not a common practice but I need to do this as this is the only way I find to navigate inside a modal, and I'm doing this for iPads.

As for `Find` and `Add`, they all have a custom `CLOSE` button to dismiss the `MyListNav` modal.

Now the question is, I know how to pass parameter from `MyListNav`(child) to `MyList`(parent), and use the state in `MyList` to control the visibility of `MyListNav`. But I **can't** find a way to pass props or state of `Find` or `Add` to `MyListNav`. Or say, I can't find a way to pass the pressing of the `CLOSE` button to `MyListNav`, as I have tried and it seems the relationship between `Find`/`Add` and `MyListNav` is not children and parent, thus can't use callback functions to do so.

Is there any regular solution for this? Or am I get it wrong somewhere??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-navigation` is kinda limited when you want to pass props to the screens.

If you aren't using `redux` your options are fairly limited.

What you can do though is pass props from the Component that initializes your Navigation down to your screens via `screenProps` which you are already doing here: `<FVN screenProps = {{isVisible: false}}/>`.

In your `Find` and `Add` screens you should be able to also see/ access the `isVisible` prop.

So you could do something like this:

`<FVN screenProps = {
  {
    isVisible: false,
    findProps: {},
    addProps: {}
  }
}/>`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I was going to use `screenProps` but realised that I needed to pass parameter from the screens to the navigator component itself. The only way in `Find`/`Add` screen I could get access to the `screenProps` is through `this.props.screenProps`, where I think its immutable. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Yes, props are immutable, and that is for good reasons.

What you rather want to do instead is to have a wrapper component that is taking care of the app state and pass down change handler(s) that will set the state of that main app root container (thus having it trickle down to all the components via props).

This way you can have a changeHandler passed down via `this.props.screenProps` which can set/ alter the app state.

Does this make sense? Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Works really good, many thanks. Learned a new way to get things done.